# In a letter, what is the most polite way to ask for a quick reply?

Tags: formal-language, correspondence

If you're writing a formal letter, and need the other party to reply as quickly as possible, how can you do it in the most polite, eloquent fashion? No matter how I try to do it, it always sounds too demanding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Although I understand that you are very busy, I would appreciate it if you could provide a response as soon as possible. I very much appreciate your time*.

My exact wording might change according to the circumstances – How well do I know the person? How important is it that I get timely feedback? Is this the first time I'm asking, or the third? What is the situation? Am I planning a reception, or arranging for payments on a loan that is about to go into default?

Those considerations aside, the generic wording I've included at the top of my answer is about as polite as I can muster.

Comment: I wonder if *"May we request a prompt reply?"* would be considered impolite or too importunate, or maybe it would be viewed as a neutral stock expression.

Comment: @Copper - Perhaps if you answered that question with an explanation, that would work just ifne. That is, something like: _May we request a prompt reply? If we're going to do this project, we'll need to start planning accordingly, so we want to commit the resources as soon as we can._ If we can somehow convince the recipient of the email that it's in **their** best interest to respond quickly, that would seem more polite, I think.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking forward to your earliest response.

We are looking forward to a timely response.

We will greatly appreciate it if you can respond at your earliest convenience.

Comment: While these may be valid sample sentence the OP can use, the answer is of little value *unless* you add some explanation to it.

Comment: @Noufil - That one is commonly used, but I'd recommend caution. Many people consider that to be rude. (See [this ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/666/thank-you-in-advance-how-to-replace) for more discussion on that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

1. An early reply would be appreciated
2. I look forward to your reply
3. I look forward to hearing from you
4. I would appreciate a reply at your earliest convenience
5. Your earliest attention would be appreciated