# "Name the file after each of which parent folder" Does this sound right?

Tags: grammar

I am trying to say that I want to name all files after each file's parent folder. Is this construction acceptable:

> Name the file after each of which parent folder.

As a non-native speaker, I am worried if this might sound too complicated. If not, what will be the natural way of saying to deliver my intention? Also, please feel free to edit my post, if this post itself contains any grammatical mistake.

Comment: Why not just say what you do in the first sentence? Where does "which" come from?

Comment: What @Catija said. You had it right with your first sentence. Stop there and don't go looking for trouble.

Comment: It's not "too complicated"; "each of which parent folder" is ungrammatical. A succinct version would be *Name each file after **its** parent folder*.  But it's not clear what you mean by "after". Are you referring to the order of operations, or saying that the file name begins with the parent folder's name and gets a numerical suffix or something else appended to differentiate it from its siblings?

Comment: I am trying to say the latter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you phrase it first is actually really good:

> Name all [of the] files after each file's parent folder.

This is a great option because it's more specific and clear than the shortened version below, which is another option if you really don't want to repeat "file".

> Name each file after its parent folder.

Your use of "which" is certainly not idiomatic. While "each of which" is definitely an idiomatic phrase, this is not how it is used.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you edit out "Thank you in advance"? Does the sentence contain any grammatical mistake?

Comment: Just found out the answer from this [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/666/thank-you-in-advance-how-to-replace):)

Comment: It's less that than that SE isn't a place for chatting so, while pleasantries are nice, they're not really encouraged here... so if someone edits your post, they're likely to remove stuff that is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, I see. This is my first time using this thread, after all:) Thanks for telling me that, Catija.